# POST is not executing for multiple post happening simultaneously android

Tags: android

i am new in android development. i am trying to make an app where it is required to execute "post" request and "get" request simultaneously, and i am using asynctask for that. it is working fine but sometimes a problem happening is while the apps trying to execute two or more "post" request at the same its executing only one "post". but i need to execute all "post" request either same time or gradually .  below code given:

```
import android.content.Context;

import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.util.Log;

import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class GetPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

//    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;


    private static String responseStr = "";
    private static String responseStrLogin = "";
    private static String responseStrSignUp = "";
    private static String responseStrFriendList = "";
    private static String responseStrUpdateLocation = "";
    private static String responseStrSettings = "";
    private static String responseStrSearchFriendForRequest = "";
    private static String responseStrSendFriendRequest = "";
    private static String responseStrUserFriendRequestList = "";
    private static String responseStrApproveFriendRequest = "";
    private static String responseStrProfileDetails = "";
    private static String responseStrCarDetails="";
    private static String responseStrCorporateDetails="";
    private static String responseStrPasswordChange="";
    private static String responseStrLocationShareToggle="";
    private static String responseStrToggleStatus="";
    private static String responseStrForgetPassword="";
    private static String responseStrSearchResult="";
    private static String responseStrDeleteFriend="";
    private static String responseStrSearchResultFriendList="";
    private static String responseStrShowFriendList="";
    private static String responseStrShowFriendProfileDetails="";
    private static String responseStrTimeSetForIndividuals="";
    private static String responseStrFriendListPeriod="";
    private static String responseStrFriendsRouteLatLng="";
    private static String responseStrDangerNotification="";
    private static String responseStrDangerNotificationPost="";



        private final String baseUrl = UserInfo.getSiteUrl();

        Context context;


        GetPostAsyncTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Loading..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                // setting the URL
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl+args[1]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "RealTimeApps/1.0");
                // setting the method type
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(args[0]);
//                httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                Log.v("Url",args[2]);
                // setting the identification key name with query params
                bufferedWriter.write(args[2]);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();

                Log.v("GetPostA", url.toString());
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                int getPostStatus = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                Log.v("GetPostSts", String.valueOf(getPostStatus));



                String line = "";
                String res = "";
//                if(getPostStatus == 200){

                    // prepare the output buffer
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                        res += line;

                    }

                    inputStream.close();

//                }

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                switch (args[3]){
                    case "1":
                        responseStrLogin = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        responseStrSignUp = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        responseStrFriendList = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        responseStrUpdateLocation = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "5":
                        responseStrSettings = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "6":
                        responseStrSearchFriendForRequest = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "7":
                        responseStrSendFriendRequest = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "8":
                        responseStrUserFriendRequestList = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "9":
                        responseStrApproveFriendRequest = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "10":
                        responseStrProfileDetails = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "11":
                        responseStrCarDetails = res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "12":
                        responseStrCorporateDetails=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "13":
                        responseStrPasswordChange=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "14":
                        responseStrLocationShareToggle=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "15":
                        responseStrToggleStatus=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "16":
                        responseStrForgetPassword=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "17":
                        responseStrSearchResult=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "18":
                        responseStrDeleteFriend=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "19":
                        responseStrSearchResultFriendList=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "20":
                        responseStrShowFriendList=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "21":
                        responseStrShowFriendProfileDetails=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "22":
                        responseStrTimeSetForIndividuals=res.toString();
                        break;
                    case "23":
                        responseStrFriendListPeriod=res.toString();
                        break;

                    case "24":
                        responseStrFriendsRouteLatLng=res.toString();
                        break;

                    case "25":
                        responseStrDangerNotification=res.toString();
                        break;

                    case "26":
                        responseStrDangerNotificationPost=res.toString();
                        break;

                    default:
                       responseStr = res.toString();
                        break;
                }
//                Log.v("ResD", res.toString());
                return res.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("GetPostCatchMal",e.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("GetPostCatchIOE", e.toString());
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

        public String getResponse(int param){
            String tmpStr = "Error";
            switch (param){
                case 1:
                    tmpStr = responseStrLogin;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    tmpStr = responseStrSignUp;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    tmpStr = responseStrFriendList;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    tmpStr = responseStrUpdateLocation;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    tmpStr = responseStrSettings;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    tmpStr = responseStrSearchFriendForRequest;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    tmpStr = responseStrSendFriendRequest;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    tmpStr = responseStrUserFriendRequestList;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    tmpStr = responseStrApproveFriendRequest;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    tmpStr = responseStrProfileDetails;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    tmpStr = responseStrCarDetails;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    tmpStr=responseStrCorporateDetails;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    tmpStr=responseStrPasswordChange;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    tmpStr=responseStrLocationShareToggle;
                    break;
                case 15:
                    tmpStr=responseStrToggleStatus;
                    break;
                case 16:
                    tmpStr=responseStrForgetPassword;
                    break;
                case 17:
                    tmpStr=responseStrSearchResult;
                    break;
                case 18:
                    tmpStr=responseStrDeleteFriend;
                    break;
                case 19:
                    tmpStr=responseStrSearchResultFriendList;
                    break;
                case 20:
                    tmpStr=responseStrShowFriendList;
                    break;
                case 21:
                    tmpStr=responseStrShowFriendProfileDetails;
                    break;
                case 22:
                    tmpStr=responseStrTimeSetForIndividuals;
                    break;
                case 23:
                    tmpStr=responseStrFriendListPeriod;
                    break;

                case 24:
                    tmpStr=responseStrFriendsRouteLatLng;
                    break;

                case 25:
                    tmpStr=responseStrDangerNotification;
                    break;

                case 26:
                    tmpStr=responseStrDangerNotificationPost;
                    break;

                default:
                    tmpStr = responseStr;
                    break;
                };

            return tmpStr;
        }


}
```

Comment: Please insert how to launch this GetPostAsyncTask. I guess you use Serial-Executer for launching Async-Task or execute it on the fly and don't use executer ?

Comment: backgroundTask.execute("POST","main/getFriendInDanger",dangerQuery,"25");

String result = backgroundTask.getResponse(25);

Answer (score 0):

Use Executer with thread-pool for launch your AsyncTask. In your case :

```
backgroundTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"POST","main/getFriendInDanger",dangerQuery,"25");
```

AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR is predeclared Executer .Of course you can make custom Executer(probably no need in your case). if you want use java.util.concurrent.Executers helper method, note that you must keep executer for application life-time and don't create executer any-time want execute AsyncTask.(you can keep your executer in static field).